# Pandas credit score comparison

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, finance, credit-card

We want to measure the credit score changes for participants of an economic.mobility program.

```
        Name        Date      Credit Score
0   John Doe  2022.01.03               653
1  Mary Jane  2022.01.05               720
2   John Doe  2022.08.14               695
3  Mary Jane  2022.09.17               640
```

Notice that some scores go up or down.

The end table should look like this:

```
Name      initial Score  updated score 
John Doe            653            695
Mary Jane           720            640
```

Using pandas, I having a hard time organizing it like this.

Grouping by date ranges (date > 2022-07-01)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) using the [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) of the dates as columns:

```
(df.assign(col=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y.%m.%d')
                 .groupby(df['Name']).rank(method='dense')
                 .map({1: 'initial Score', 2: 'updated score'})
          )
   .pivot(index='Name', columns='col', values='Credit Score')
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Alternatively, using `2022-07-01` as a threshold:

```
(df.assign(col=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y.%m.%d')
                 .gt('2022-07-01')
                 .map({False: 'initial Score', True: 'updated score'})
          )
   .pivot(index='Name', columns='col', values='Credit Score')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
          Name  initial Score  updated score
0     John Doe            653            695
1    Mary Jane            720            640
```